# Getting yyyymm from two columns in df where year is yyyy and month is just m

Tags: date, concatenation

```
<existing  > [Required]
Year  Month   Year_mnth
1942    1      194201
1942    2      194202
1942    3      194203
...
1942   10      194210
1942   11      194211
1942   12      194212
```

cant added the required zero to make them all yyyymm

Comment: Search zero padding on so

Comment: How could I code a new column called yyyymm = (Year*100)+ Month which will give the result I need in int format

Comment: please update the question with the code you've attempted

Comment: does the input consist solely of the 2 columns, or are there other data fields that need to be ignored? if the latter, please update the question with a sample of your actual input

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` and ask `printf` to make zero padding:

```
$ printf '%.2d\n' 1
01
$ printf '%.2d\n' 10
10
```

I give just hints, **so** is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

in a bash loop with printf format to left pad with zeros

```
$ while read yr mo; do printf "%s%02d\n" "$yr" "$mo"; done < file
194201
194202
194203
194210
194211
194212
```

Answer (score 0):

you could `printf` it, or just multiply year by 100 :

> ```
> mawk '$++NF = 100 * $++_ + $(_+_--)'
> ```

```
 1942 1 194201 194201
 1942 2 194202 194202
 1942 3 194203 194203
 ...
 1942 10 194210 194210
 1942 11 194211 194211
 1942 12 194212 194212
```

another more brute force approach involves just `substr()` :

> ```
> nawk '$++NF = $1 substr("0"$2, length($2), 2)'
> ```

- or

> ```
> gawk '$++NF = $1 substr("0", length($2)) $2'
> ```

```
 1942 1 194201 194201
 1942 2 194202 194202
 1942 3 194203 194203
 ...
 1942 10 194210 194210
 1942 11 194211 194211
 1942 12 194212 194212
```